# How to copy file from network path to local location with WCF Webservice?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

My webservice is attempting to do a file copy from a network path (\myserver\data\file.dat) to a local location (C:\temp\file.dat).

```
File.Copy(NetworkPath, LocalPath, true);
```

However I am getting the following exception when I test my code using WCF Test Client.

> Access to the path '\myserver\data\file.dat' is denied.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: write all path: `File.Copy("\\serverA\path\to\file", "\\serverB\path\to\file")`

Comment: Does the user who is executing the WCF webservice have rights on the network share? The default IIS identity is a user with very few rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IIS, you need to make sure that the user which is set up for the application pool that your WCF service is using has proper access rights to the folder (write access in this case).

You may need to replace the default user with another one that you should create for that purpose as the default user has limited access to file system.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the Application Pool identity to my user identity and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @Szymon what if I am hosting on local and accessing network drive(I am not able to create file I can read it).